# Unexpected Error while trying to upload .jmx file into Jmeter

Tags: file, jmeter, upload, blazemeter

I am using JMeter 5.4 version and I cant upload recorded Blazemeter .jmx file. Below the screenshot for reference

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is very nice, however if you need assistance it's better to provide the `jmeter.log` file contents (and better in textual form rather than as a screenshot), this way the chance of getting a comprehensive answer will be much higher.

The `jmeter.log` file lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation (or in the place where you launched JMeter from in case of using shortcuts), see [Logging and error messages](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) user manual chapter for more details.

The majority of "impossible to open .jmx script" problems are connected with missing JMeter Plugin, i.e. [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) produces [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and if you don't have this plugin installed - you won't be able to open the Test Plan so if you won't be able to figure out the root cause of the failure try installing [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) and if the error is due to a missing plugin - it will pop up a window suggesting to install missing plugins or upgrade existing to the appropriate version